# Cassandra UUID partition key and partition size

Tags: cassandra, primary-key, partition

Given a table

```
CREATE TABLE sensors_by_id (
    id uuid,
    time timeuuid,
    some_text text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, time)
)
```

Will this scale when there are a lot of entries? I´m not sure, if a UUID field is sufficient as a good partition key or is there a need to create some artificial key like week_first_day or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really depends on how will you insert your data - if you generate the UUID really randomly for every insert, then the chance of duplicates [is very low](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#uuid), and you'll get so-called "skinny rows" (a lot of partitions with 1 row inside). Even if you start to get the duplicates, there will be not so many for every row...

Comment: Thank you. I´m not worried about duplicates that much at this point. Skinny rows seem to distribute fine in a cluster, so it´s a "go"?

Comment: Yes, that's a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem with partition size cause cassandra has limit for disk size per one partition.

Good rule of thumb is to keep the maximum number of rows below **100,000 items** and the **disk size under 100 MB**.

It is easy to calculate partition size by using that formula[image]

You  can read more about data modeling [here](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/cassandra-data-modeling).

So in your case with current schema for **1 000 000** rows count **per one partition** with average size **100** byte for **some_text** column will be:

```
Number of Values: (1000000 * (3 - 2 - 0) + 0) = 1000000

Partition Size on Disk: (16 + 0 + (1000000 * 116) + (8 * 1000000))
= 124000016 bytes (118.26 Mb)
```

So as you can see you out of limit with **118.26 Mb** per one partition. So you need optimize your partition keys.

I calculated it using my open source project - [cql-calculator](https://github.com/johnnywidth/cql-calculator).